# Modern alternatives of DNA footprinting

Tags: molecular-biology, biotechnology

Since DNA footprinting is an old method I thought there may be some more recent and effective methods to identify a DNA sequence, do you know any of them?

Comment: You could look into ChIP-Seq

Comment: Identify it as what? Guess the species of origin? Guess the individual it came from? Guess its function?

Comment: Since he is talking about footprinting, I assume he wants to identify what motif a particular protein binds.

Comment: @canadianer ah! _DNAse_ footprinting, OK.

Answer (score 2):

[DNAse-seq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNase-Seq) is the most obvious choice. It uses the same idea as DNAse footprinting but measures output using high-throughput sequencing, so it can be done on a whole genome in one shot.

Answer (score 1):

DNA sequencing, RFLP, IHC, *In Situ* Hybridization, Southern Blotting.

I think the technique you are looking for (what you are talking about), is an Electro Mobility Shift Assay or EMSA